# Make <select> in table cell occupy entire row height

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put a  drop-down menu in a table cell, and have the menu (when not dropped down) occupy the entire height of the cell?  Using just html & css?

I want the user to be able to click anywhere in the cell to activate the drop-down.

The row heights vary unpredictably, so hard-coding a constant height isn't possible.

Below is a demo .html file.  Here's what I get in Firefox 84.0.  I want the drop-down in the second row to occupy the full height of the row.

[image]

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head> <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
table {
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
th, td { 
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: small;
} 
select {
  border: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Short and to the point.</td>
    <td>
      <select> <option>Apple</option> <option>Orange</option> </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A multi-line (or wrapped)<br />message<br />makes this row higher</td>   
    <td>
      <select> <option>Apple</option> <option>Orange</option> </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this. I have added some css and 100% width height to the select. I have only added to the second select, but you can make that to the css to apply it for all select.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px lightblue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%;
}

table th td {
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: small;
}

table td {
    border: solid 1px lightblue;
    height: 100%;
}

select {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Short and to the point.</td>
    <td>
      <select> <option>Apple</option> <option>Orange</option> </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A multi-line (or wrapped)<br />message<br />makes this row higher</td>   
    <td>
      <select> <option>Apple</option> <option>Orange</option> </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You may want to check browser compatibility—the `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` show no change to the element size in Firefox.

Comment: @karolus check firefox now. changed the css part a bit.

Comment: @A Paul: I did some more testing, and have it up in edits—this is the working code.

Comment: @A Paul: Can you approve the suggested edits? I found the fix by adding `height: 100%` to containing elements, and cleaned up the code by moving inline CSS to the head section.

Comment: Question: It seems like the key change to make the drop-down fill the row height is 

table { height:100%; ...}

But why does that fix the problem?   Doesn't table height:100% mean make the entire table (all rows combined) match the height of the enclosing object (<html> in this case)?

Comment: @jimav This depends upon how the browser populate it. If table has a 100% height then it can fit any content as it knows the table can take the full height, but if no height then the table calculation will not know if it can do 100% of the cell due to other cell contents. That's my understanding. Not 100% clear